# Custom Visual Studio offline install

Tags: visual-studio, installation

In order to deploy on many computers offline, I use the layout command line argument to get setup files. Easy and OK.

Then I can install it with the "--in response.template.json " argument.

But is there any way to build json automatically from custom setup before or after execution ? 
It's very hard to build ***detailed options*** manually because of dependencies and sometimes unmeaning names for me.

Thanks for your help.

**Very short sample lines from the JSON response template file :**

> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools", 
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.IISDevelopment", 
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core", 
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Win81", 
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard", 
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC", 
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin", 
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtension.Prerequisites",

Comment: How did you use `--in response.template.json`? Did you use this argument to install the offline vs package on other PC? And I wonder what the purpose of building json automatically from custom setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which let me look again :)     With 2017, I did use the GUI to choose custom options and get in the temp directories the needed configuration file. It was far easier (dynamic space requirements) to choose and create the file. It appears than since 2017 (15.9), they did add a great parameter : "export" which do the same. And yes, I did use this file on many computers, working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2017 (15.9), the parameter "**export**" allows to select components in the setup GUI to save the configuration file. Then it's easy to deploy the customized setup on many computers. There is a small problem, space requirements doesn't appear when selecting modules.